# Hide non-printable characters in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I am trying to create a new class in a default package, I am getting the following non printable characters:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to

Window → Preferences → General → Editors → Text Editors

untick the "Show whitespace characters":

[image]

And they'll go away.

Answer (score 2):

Click on "Show Whitespace Characters" icon in the menubar

[image]